# How to redirect from one controller to another with params in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have created a registration page for new user and company.I dont want to use default signup page which is already there because I have many custom fields. After creating new user and company I want to display user details in a new page. I am getting error as `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`. How to redirect from '/web/save' api to '/web/details' api with my parameter 'qcontext'.

```py
@http.route('/web/save', type='http', method="post", auth="public",csrf=False)
def save_registration_details(self, **kw):
    qcontext = request.params.copy()
    # Code to create new user and company 

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'url': '/web/details/%s' % qcontext,
        'target': 'self',
    }

@http.route('/web/details', type='http', auth="public")
def show_registration_details(self, qcontext, redirect=None, **kw):
    return http.request.render('odoo_web_login.success',qcontext)
```

Comment: return http.request.render('odoo_web_login.success', qcontext=qcontext)
and no need to write qcontext as arg in method.

Comment: I want to redirect from /web/save to /web/details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```py
return werkzeug.utils.redirect('/web/details%s' % qcontext)
```

Comment: I am getting error as AttributeError: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'redirect'

Comment: I see.
You can also try:

    return werkzeug.utils.redirect('/web/details/%s' % qcontext)

please let me know if it works, and i'll edit my answer.

Comment: werkzeug.utils.redirect is working but I am getting 404 error for /web/details/ so what should I change in @http.route('/web/details', type='http', auth="public")?

Comment: do you also have a 404 error for '/web/details'? the ending slash matters

Comment: I changed it to /web/details/<string:qcontext>' Now I can pass integer or string but my variable 'qcontext' is of type dictionary.So how to pass dictionary variable correctly.Thanks in advance

Comment: I am passing all the params separately to 'web/details/' api so now its working

Answer (score 0):

For redirect from One controller to another return url like this:

```
return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'url': '/web/details?qcontext=%s&redirect=True' % (qcontext),
        'target': 'self',
    }
```